# Возможно ли подключить динамический svg-файл на html-страницу с тегом <img src=""/>?

Tags: html, svg

У меня есть svg-картинка, которая подключает другую картинку, используя URL взятый из hash-части собственного адреса:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <script>
    <![CDATA[
    let xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    let image = document.createElementNS(xmlns,'image');
    image.setAttribute('href', location.hash.substr(1));
    image.setAttribute('x', "0");
    image.setAttribute('y', "0");
    image.setAttribute('width', "1000");
    image.setAttribute('height', "1000");
    document.documentElement.appendChild(image);
    ]]>
  </script>
</svg>
```

Если я подключаю этот SVG с помощью тега IFRAME, то все работает как надо, но хочется, чтобы работало и через тег IMG:

```
<iframe src="test.svg#test.jpeg"></iframe>  <!-- так работает -->


<img src="test.svg#test.jpeg" />            <!-- так не работает -->
```

Не смотря на то, что ничего не отображается, браузер загружает оба файла и test.svg и test.jpeg и после загрузки элемент IMG даже принимает размер картинки test.jpeg. Но почему-то не хочет отображать кроме прозрачного распора. Что надо сделать с SVG-картинкой, чтобы она могла работать подключаясь тегом IMG?

Comment: @Айболит  Я делаю мини-скрипт хостинга картинок с шифрованием на клиенте и расшифровкой на клиенте. Ключ шифрования помещается в ссылку на картинку и не передается на сервер. Все работает. Теперь мне нужно предоставить прямые ссылки для вставки картинки на форумы/другие сайты, поддерживающие bb-код, md-код или html-код. Так возможно сделать через svg или как-нибудь еще?

Comment: @Айболит то есть я как хочу сделать... даю прямую ссылку на svg-картинку. Эта svg-картинка содержит скрипт для расшифровки файла картинки. В идеале должно работать также, отображая картинку не отправляя ключ на сервер. Ну а сами ссылки будут размещаться на других ресурсах. Врядли где-то подключают картинки через iframe... по крайней мере, я не слышал...

Comment: С помощью `object` работает, но размер для изображения не действует.

Comment: @Leonid размер я могу выставить вручную, отображал бы хоть что-то

Comment: `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"/>` - так попробуйте, правда с id я не пробовал, потому как не ясно откуда `#text.jpg` должен браться. У вас же в тело svg добавляется тег image с динамическим адресом. Элементов с id="text.jpg" нет.

Comment: @Leonid элементов с id `#text.jpg` нету, а картинка берет URL из адреса `location.hash.substr(1)`. :-)

Comment: Я думал хэш страницы берете для сложения значения или еще чего, тогда зачем все эти муки, если адрес изображения сразу в атрибуте содержится?))) Я то напрямую задал адрес, а `location` возвращает действительно адрес svg, но есть `location.origin`, вроде. Мало ли что вам нужно)) У меня то на то и другое выводит один номер локалхоста, трудно определить что к чему)) Так в <object> подходит или нет?

Comment: @Leonid приношу извинения, мой косяк, надо было в вопросе детальнее описать. Причину я немного описал в первых двух комментариях.

Comment: Я прочитал, но толком не понял. Значит именно через тег `img` надо? Может просто dataURL подавать на src? Я так и не понял о каких ключах идет речь и где именно они расшифровываются, в скрипте SVG? Если скрипт на странице запускается, то ведь не проблема и любое поведение для элементов определить. Короче многое не ясно.

Comment: @Leonid Да скрипт расшифровки там простой... используется браузерная функция [`crypto.subtle.decrypt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt).Но ссылка нужна прямая, жалательно не svg вовсе... Но и сам тег img расшифровать картинку не сможет конечно, надо запускать скрипт минимум из одной строки точно... Svg тут как прослойка для выполнения скрипта